# Isotope/Masonry extra height with images

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I've implemented Isoptope, but the same seems to happen with masonry. My containers are LI's with images. Currently i have a local and some images from instagram the LI's have bg color to i can help troubleshoot. The images have a width set to 100% through CSS which gives them the same width as the parent. I have tried forcing this with the img tag.

The site is here: http://template.markjhandy.com/

I'm currently trouble shooting this, but i won't push any new code for awhile.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hey Jeff, ideally, the images would stack with no space. Ideally the container heights will depend on the images since images may be portrait or landscape so heights may not be fixes.

Cheers!

Comment: I've updated the code base to allow for double rows. I think i may know what is the issues is. I disabled the isotope plugin, and still have the extra height on the container. I'm going to look at the CSS reset.

Comment: found the issue. Line height.

It was solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920434/5px-extra-margin-getting-added-to-the-bottom-of-each-div

Thanks!