# IMG has 5px extra padding at bottom of div

Tags: css

I have a div that has a mystery 5px bottom padding added to an image contained within it. I've tried resetting CSS padding and margin for all elements but to no avail. What am I missing?:

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/vbFx9/

HTML:

```
<div id="list">
    <div id="boxscroll">
        <div class="list-result">
            <img src="images/ps-result.png">
        </div>
        <div class="list-result">
            <img src="images/ps-result.png">
        </div>
        <div class="list-result">
            <img src="images/ps-result.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.list-result {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
    background:#f9f9f9;
}
.list-result:hover {
    background:#e9e9e9;
}
#list {
    top: 100px;
    bottom:40px;
    right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    max-width:300px;
}
#boxscroll {
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    background:#f9f9f9;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height:100%;
    border: 8px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: please accept the answer below as it most definitely appears to be the correct, working solution.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

use the following css: [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbFx9/1/)

```
img{display:block;}
```

Images are by default displayed inline - which causes the padding below the image. (because of line-height)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Am I understanding this correctly: any inline content needs to leave some space at its bottom so this space can be used by the lower parts of letters like 'g', 'y' etc. Is that what causes the problem? Or is the space between separate lines what causes it?

Comment: @StefanMonov actually the two things are attached to one another, the line height is affected by the font size (leaving a gap for lower parts letters as you said). This issue could also be solved by setting the `font-size` to 0 (thus no additional height is needed) or forcing the `line-height` to be 0 (this will ofcourse create a vertical scroll bar). Also, any whitespace after an inline element will be considered as ' ' (space) in HTML.. All these combined, explain why treating the images as blocks makes most sense in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9185126/764754). Use

```
.list-result {    
  line-height: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbFx9/17/)

Answer (score 0):

use `display: inline-block;` to your image

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vbFx9/2/)